# Android Transparant color works differently on different devices

Tags: android, android-color

I'm have a fragment whose BG should be semi transparent. So, I'm using `<color name="transparent75">#BF000000</color>` which is 75% black transparency.

It looks good on Samsung S4, but it is too transparent on Sony device. I'm googling from a while and couldn't get any proper solution.

Any solutions much appreciated.

Comment: I think is because of the screen technology ,  since AMOLED screens have darker blacks is going to look darker, and IPS screens going to be lighter, since your transparency is based on the colour black, is gona look slightly different on different screens .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think every screen was made equal. I have tried comparing white background on nexus 5 and Samsung s4, the result is different.

I found a discussion about color reproduction [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus6/comments/2thss7/colours_on_the_nexus_6_display_look_different/). Maybe this is what you're experiencing right now.

> The screen technology is different between the nexus 5 and 6. The 5 uses an IPS screen that is backlit and is generally considered superior at reproducing whites, and colors tend to be more life-like.
>   The nexus 6 has an Amoled screen - it is not back lit, with each pixel lighting up individually. Amoled screens are great at reproducing blacks, and are also generally more saturated when it comes to colors. - **Jakshadows26**

Comment: Thanks you. Totally agree with you. Do u think there is any possible solution for this situation?

Comment: it is necessary for you to have exact color reproduction on every screen? I think it is quite impossible to provide solution for this.

Comment: The problem for me is.. The texts on the transparent fragment are not clear to read as they are overlaping with the texts in the underneath fragment.. and its on Sony